# Select timeout error on BeagleBone Black

Tags: python, linux, opencv

I am testing an opencv video capture code on my BBB (running Debian Wheezy: Linux beaglebone 3.8.13-bone79 #1 SMP Tue Oct 13 20:44:55 UTC 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux) but getting a select timeout error everytime i run the program. Now i am behind schedule of my final year Iris recognition system Project. (In case you want to know why i am going through this video capture code, it is for tracking the eyes then capture an image that will be processed to obtain an IrisCode.)

I installed opencv 3.0.0 following instructions on http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/#comment-393561 , but had to turn off ffmpeg (suggested on one of the forums: [OpenCV 3.0.0 make error with FFMPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31663498/opencv-3-0-0-make-error-with-ffmpeg/31818445#31818445) ) after obtaining a compilation errors but firstly i had compiled ffmpeg from source.

Below is the Video_Capturing code i tested with;

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
     # Capture frame-by-frame
     ret, frame = cap.read()

 # Our operations on the frame come here
 gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

 # Display the resulting frame
 cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
 if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
     break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

After running the code i am obtaining the following information  (Note: The frame is only opening when i run the python script in LXTerminal accessed through tightvnc. It is failing to run through ssh);

```
root@beaglebone:~/Project/Testing# python Video_Streaming.py

(process:1488): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
        Using the fallback 'C' locale.
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1".
select timeout
select timeout
select timeout
select timeout
^Cselect timeout
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Video_Streaming.py", line 8, in <module>
    ret, frame = cap.read()
KeyboardInterrupt
root@beaglebone:~/Project/Testing#
```

I'm stuck i need your help.